# Make each section appear to the left/right of the line in the middle

Tags: html, css

I have this green line down the middle of the page, how can I make it so that each section appears on the left then the right, for example section 1 at the top and to the left, section2 on the right hand side and a little lower than the next one.

So on so forth

```css
#line {
  height: 500px;
  width: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='about'>
  <h2>About</h2>
  <p>A little journey throguh my life/career</p>
  <div class='timeline'>
    <div id='line'></div>
    <div id='section1'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section2'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section3'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section4'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section5'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating the line as a separate element is just going to cause you problems giving it the right height.

Make the line a border, and use the odd or even position of the div to design which side to push it to and which side to draw the line on.

```css
.timeline > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.timeline > div:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right: calc(50% - 3px);
    border-right: 5px solid green;
}

.timeline > div:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 3px);
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class='about'>
  <h2>About</h2>
  <p>A little journey throguh my life/career</p>
  <div class='timeline'>
    <div id='section1'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section2'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section3'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section4'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div id='section5'>
      <h3>xx.xx.xxxx</h3>
      <h3>Timeline Section Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque voluptatum quis perferendis consectetur distinctio sequi et laborum modi mollitia iste eum doloribus vel, ea eos, molestias explicabo cumque ut, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#section1,
#section3,
#section5{
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#section2,
#section4{
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the HTML structure, you can do it like this:

**1)** Add a class to the sections, something like `.section`.

```
<div class="section" id='section1'>
...
</div>
<div class="section" id='section2'>
...
</div>
<div class="section" id='section3'>
...
</div>
...
```

**2)** Then, change the relative position to absolute position for the line element, so it will be absolutely positioned in the middle.

```
#line {
  height: 500px;
  width: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

**3)** Finally, make each section 50% of the total width and use `nth-of-type()` selector to make it alternating from left to right using a margin-left for the sections that will be on the right side.

```
.timeline .section:nth-of-type(2n) {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.section {
  width: 50%;
}
```

If you want to make each section a little lower than the previous one, you can add some negative margin, which is a little bit hacky, but can work well in this case.

The first section doesn't need it. The selector is number 2 because it is the second child, not the first. The first is the about div element.

```
.section {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.timeline .section:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```